# Using Python subprocess.call() to launch an ncurses process

Tags: python, linux, ncurses, scons, crosstool-ng

I'm trying to call ct-ng (http://crosstool-ng.org/) from a SCons SConstruct script, so basically from Python.

**using the following method:**

```
 ret =  subprocess.call(["/mnt/build/pw_build/crosstool-ng/bin/ct-ng  menuconfig"], env=env_cross,shell=True)
```

**crosstool-ng uses ncurses to present the user with a menu:**

[image]

**Unfortunately when trying to navigate the menus I get:**

[image]

**Using cat to display the sequences when using the arrow keys I see:**

```
:/mnt/build$ cat > /dev/null
^[OA^[OD^[OB^[OC^[OA^[OB^[OD^[OC^[OA^[OB
```

It seems like something is possibly stripping the escape characters from the sequence.

When I call the ct-ng script from the command line in the terminal it works correctly, it is when I call it using *subprocess.call()* that things go bad.

**My environment consists of:**

- xfce4-terminal 0.6.3
- Linux 3.13.0-32-lowlatency #57-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Tue Jul 15 04:08:59
  UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- Python 2.7.6
- NCURSES_VERSION "5.9"
- GNU Make 3.81
- crosstool-NG version 1.19.0

Is what I am seeing a known problem? Is there something else I should be doing?

UPDATE:
 Thanks Eric... That got me 0.5f way there... I can navigate the menu now, but it still leaves droppings behind:

[image]

Comment: Your shell is interpreting your keystrokes I bet.  Try "stty raw ; crosstool thingie ; stty cooked".  Raw might be too extreme, but it may verify the cause of the problem.

Comment: OK... try "stty -echo" (instead of raw)

Comment: No love from -echo, currently trying some variations with stty...

Comment: Tried everything I could think of, still can't get it to work properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run curses programs under Python I'd recommend that you use [pexpect](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html).

For example here's a simple program that starts a copy of `vim`, add some text, escape to command mode, issue a :w command, and then interact with the user (allowing him or her to continue editing or whatever).  Then the control returns to Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pexpect
child = pexpect.spawn("/usr/bin/vim")
child.send('a\n\nThis is another test.')
child.send('\x1b')
child.send(':w! test.txt\n')
child.interact()
```

You can also pass arguments (such as escape character, and filter functions for input and output) to the interact method.  But those get a bit tricky.  (On the other hand they then become your custom keyboard macro system interposed between users and the application being run under the `.spawn()`).

(BTW: you can send your desired sequences of keystrokes into this `ct-ng` dialog/menu ... it's just a matter of figuring out what those sequences need to be for your terminal settings.  For example on my iTerm under MacOS X running with TERM=xterm-256color a "down arrow" cursor movement comes out as ^[[B ([Esc][Bracket][B]). That would be '\x1b[B' as a Python string literal).

Answer (score 0):

After careful tracing of the execution there was a script redirecting to `tee` that was causing the problem.

Thanks to everyone who looked at the problem. I should have seen that in the first place; sorry for the noise.

Comment: If the issue was a user error, likely you should delete the original question?