# Real-time colour refreshing output from python's subprocess.Popen()

Tags: python, python-3.x

There are some commands in Linux with "fancy" output - by "fancy" I mean that it is colourful and it is real-time ie it *overwrites* itself, the best example is the output of the `top` command, [another example could be](https://youtu.be/5EuDY6ayNs8?t=299) `docker build` (it refreshes times (`0.5s` in the example below) interactively during build, see the demo):

```
[+] Building 0.5s (3/3) FINISHED                                                                                                                                
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                  0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile             0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 518B                             0.0s
 => ERROR resolve image config for ...                           0.5s
...
```

My question, is how can I have the same output while running a process in Python (presumably with `subprocess.Popen`)? I am primarily interested in Linux.

---

PS
The closest I could achieve was colourful output via allocating tty:

```
out_r, out_w = pty.openpty()
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=out_w, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
os.close(out_w)
while True:
   try:
      output = os.read(out_r, 1000).decode()
      print(output)
```

But it, unsurprisingly, prints everything *below*, without rewriting content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the right words to Google were **ncurses/curses**, which immediately led me to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24946988/using-python-subprocess-call-to-launch-an-ncurses-process).

The following couple of lines worked for me like a charm:

```
import pexpect
child = pexpect.spawn(<command_line_str>)
child.interact()
```